# How to persist a complex data structure in Swift, advice on a way forward

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, struct, enums

I have completed a card game in Xcode 6 and swift.  The following is

```
enum Rank: Int {
case Ace = 1
case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
case Jack, Queen, King
var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .Ace:
        return "ace"
    case .Jack:
        return "jack"
    case .Queen:
        return "queen"
    case .King:
        return "king"
    default:
        return String(self.rawValue)
    }
}
}

enum Suit {
case Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs
static let allValues = [Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs]
var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .Spades:
        return "spades"
    case .Hearts:
        return "hearts"
    case .Diamonds:
        return "diamonds"
    case .Clubs:
        return "clubs"
    }
}
}

struct AbstractCard {
var rank: Rank
var suit: Suit
var faceup: Bool
var description: String {
    return "\(rank.description) of \(suit.description)"
}
var facedown: Bool {return !faceup}
var color: String {
    return suit.color
}
}


struct AbstractPile {
var cards:[AbstractCard] = []
}

struct AbstractStack {
var cards:[AbstractCard] = []
}
```

Suffice it to say the game is complete and working.  This abstract stuff is for the game logic and parallels SKNodes which represent them.

The big question, how in heck do I get the game to persist?  I'd like to store the AbstractPile and the AbstractStack somehow and then retrieve them.

I've already got methods for the physical stacks to mirror the abstract stacks etc..., so all I need to do is persist these structures.

I am at a loss as progressing through the NSCoding way leads me to a wall once I get to nscoding the AbstractPile.  Here is where I get stumped

```
class AbstractPile: NSCoding {
var cards:[AbstractCard] = []
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeArrayOfObjCType(type:, count: cards.count, at: <#UnsafePointer<Void>#>)
}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    cards = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("cards") as [AbstractPile]
}
}
```

Please help!

Comment: You can see I walked the path of turning everything to classes, but where do I go once I get to nscoding an array of class abstract card which is made up of enums?

Answer (score 0):

For those who ended up here, I decided to go down the route of using a plist to store the values in the game.  I encoded them myself using functions in the enums to encode (turn to a string, i.e. Ace_Hearts_faceup) and decode the strings.  I then saved the strings in a plist and reloaded from the plist.

I really didn't see any alternative.  Core Data is beyond the scope of this, and using NSEncode, while great for scenes, really is too complicated for storing abstract information.